# Why does e.target return undefined when trying to change an inputs value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I know this question has been asked before but the solutions posted there didn't correct my issue.

So I'm working with React and have a component. Everything else works fine, but now I'm trying to use a few useStates to get dynamic information as I intend to connect to an API/server further down the line.

I'm also using styled-components, which is why you'll see odd tag names. These work fine because I worked on them first and have them visible when I run `npm start`

The issue is that when I try to type something other than 0 in to this input, it refuses to update and gives me `e.target is undefined`

Here's where my error is occuring (on the `e.target.value`):

```
<InnerWrap flexColumn>
    <AttributeFrame>

        <EngravingInput 
            type= "text" 
            placeholder="20" 
            inputWidth="50px" 
            name="charSTR" 
            value={charAttributes.charSTR} 
            onChange={(e) => handle_attr_Change(e.target.value)}/>

        <Spacer />
        <>{((charAttributes.charSTR)-10)/2}</>
        <>STR</>
    </AttributeFrame>
</InnerWrap>
```

Here's the useState (Recently learned I could put multiple fields in a single useState):

```
    const [charAttributes, set_CharAttributes] = useState(
        {
          charSTR: 0,
          charSTRmod: 0  
        });
```

Then, here's the function that's supposed to fire on the `onChange` part of my element input:

```
//This is in my component definition, before the return block
    const handle_attr_Change = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        set_CharAttributes(
            {
            ...charAttributes,
            [e.target.name]: value
            }
        );
```

The whole idea is that the charSTRmod value is supposed to update whenever the user types in a number. It's meant to calculate the attribute bonus for a strength attribute from DnD 5e.

Screengrab of the part:

[image: Screenshot showing the elements rendered]

Please could someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Either use `e.target.value` in the `onChange` handler or in `handle_attr_Change`. You're using them in both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the event itself `e` into `handle_attr_Change` instead of unpacking it:

```js
<EngravingInput 
  ...
  onChange={handle_attr_Change}
/>
...
const handle_attr_Change = (e) => {
  set_CharAttributes(
    {
       ...charAttributes,
       [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }
  );
...
```

Comment: @Mario Petrovic Why the edit? Doesn't the edit essentially reverted the code to the broken state?

Comment: You are right, but your code did not pass `e` so  it can be used to get `e.target.name`. Can you edit your answer so that `onChange` is set to `handle_attr_Change` function, not called in callback

Comment: Instead of this `onChange={(e) => handle_attr_Change(e.target.value)}/>` put this `onChange={handle_attr_Change}`

Comment: OK. That works. Why is that better than passing `e.target.value` into `handle_attr_Change`?

Comment: Well if you do what i suggested, you dont need to  pass two values to `handle_attr_change`. In your case you need to do this: `handle_attr_Change(e.target.value, e.target.name)`. I case of giving `onChange={handle_attr_Change}` you just need to use `e` in that function `handle_attr_Change`

Comment: That's fair. I didn't notice OP was using the `target.name` as well.